# How to get transient DbContext in ASP.NET MVC Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have the following in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Sqlite")));
```

Now, I'd like to fire up an instance of `MyDbContext` that has a transient lifetime. The reason for doing so is because I'm populating my cache at startup. So how can I get an instance of `MyDbContext` that I'm responsible for disposing of myself? I have an `IServiceProvider` ready at hand.

```
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
```

throws an exception which says it's out of scope.

I understand why the exception is getting thrown, but I'm not sure what the best way of getting around it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a scope manually something like this:

```
using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider; 
    scopedServices.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();

     ...
}
```

this will give a scoped dbcontext that will get automatically disposed by the scope closure when you are finished using it. During web requests there is a scope created automatically per request so it gets disposed at the end of the request.

Comment: Question: I'm assuming I don't need to Dipose() the ctx because when the scope ends, there's already some logic in place that does it, or pools it?

Comment: right the using that wraps the scope is what ends the scope and disposes scoped resource created with the scope.